# Cant read server response over SSL in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I have a custom class in my application that creates a socket with a server and reads the output from the server. the problem is that the output is not right. for what i see the output is coming under ssl cryptography, and when i read it it is wrong.

this is the method from witch i create the ssl connection

```
  def self.feedback_connection
    raise "The path to your pem file is not set. (APNS.pem = /path/to/cert.pem)" unless self.pem
    raise "The path to your pem file does not exist!" unless File.exist?(self.pem)

    context      = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(self.pem))
    context.key  = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(self.pem), self.pass)

    fhost = self.host.gsub('gateway','feedback')
    puts fhost

    sock         = TCPSocket.new(fhost, 2196)
    sock.setsockopt Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_KEEPALIVE, true
    ssl          = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock,context)
    ssl.sync = true
    ssl.connect

    return sock, ssl
  end
```

then, in my main metodh

```
  def self.feedback
    sock, ssl = self.feedback_connection

    apns_feedback = []

    while line = sock.gets # Read lines from the socket << the problem is here
      line.strip!
      f = line.unpack('N1n1H140')       
      apns_feedback << [Time.at(f[0]), f[2]]
    end

    ssl.close
    sock.close

    return apns_feedback
  end
```

in the line: `while line = sock.gets` if i use `sock.gets` i get the codified string. if i use the `ssl.read(38)` this returns null.

i need to read 38 bytes at the time, in this disposition:

```
1..4 => timestamp (big endian)
5..6 => length (big endian)
7..38 => token (binary) quoting: The token in binary format.
```

so my problem is: with ssl i cant read at all, with socket everytime i get a diferent string

what can i do to read the right information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

The server wasn't sending anything, because the ssl protocol, the empty response in ssl is something unreadable without ssl.

After checking that, everything work fine.